# Как выбрать все записи с нескольких таблиц в одном запросе?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Мне необходимо выбрать все поля из 7 таблиц, в одном запросе. Какой запрос должен быть ?

Есть таблицы: table1, table2,table3. в них одинаковые поля id, name, address.
Мне нужно с помощью php положить это всё в массив и вывести результат через цикл.

Делаю так и получаю пустой результат.

```
                            <?php
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `psn`,`office`,`zdanie`,`tp`,`sklad`,`bussines`,`zemlya` LIMIT 15";
                            $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                                echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>".$row['id_obj']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['bid_type']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['category']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['address']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['price']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['area']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['namesob']."</td>
                                        <td>".$row['phone']."</td> 
                                        <td><img src='/img/icon_edit_object.png'></td>                                
                                    </tr>                                    
                                ";
                            }
                        ?>
```

Как правильно составить запрос, чтобы данные всех таблиц, поместить в массив ?
Спасибо.

Comment: А можно нескромный вопрос: зачем 7 таблиц с одинаковой структурой? Можно же сделать одну таблицу + доп. столбец, в котором указывать тип объекта. Ответ на ваш вопрос - `UNION`. Почитайте на досуге. Запрос будет в стиле `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2`

Comment: Там у каждого объекта свои доп. поля, разного количества) поэтому так решил сделать) спасибо за помощь, разобрался)

Comment: Можете ответ опубликовать?

Comment: нормализация для слабаков

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо, получилось вот так:

```
$query = "SELECT id_obj,bid_type,category,address,price,area,namesob,phone,time_created FROM `psn` UNION SELECT id_obj,bid_type,category,address,price,area,namesob,phone,time_created FROM `office` UNION SELECT id_obj,bid_type,category,address,price,area,namesob,phone,time_created FROM `zdanie` UNION SELECT id_obj,bid_type,category,address,price,area,namesob,phone,time_created FROM `tp` UNION SELECT id_obj,bid_type,category,address,price,area,namesob,phone,time_created FROM `sklad` UNION SELECT id_obj,bid_type,category,address,price,area,namesob,phone,time_created FROM `bussines` UNION SELECT id_obj,bid_type,category,address,price,area,namesob,phone,time_created FROM `zemlya` ORDER BY `time_created` DESC LIMIT 15";

$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Еще и `mysql_` функции до кучи)